# Generic Parsing Error

Tags: parsing, syntax-error, runtime-error, 4d-database

In a 4D application, I have the following lines of code:

```
Begin SQL
UPDATE Keys
   SET Desc = :$desc,
       KeyStamp = :$key_stamp
 WHERE KeyTitle = :$key_title
End SQL
```

When trying to run the code, the following error is displayed:

> Generic parsing error. Parsing failed in or around the following
>   substring interval - ( 16, 23 ) - ... SET Desc = ...

Does anyone see the problem with the code? `Keys` is not a keyword or anything, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like someone forgot that `Desc` is a keyword for "descending." The solution is to rename the column and update all references to that column. Otherwise, the column cannot be referenced in SQL.